# How to convert latex formula without pressing 'enter' in office word

Tags: microsoft-word

Microsoft Word now has a nice LaTeX feature, but after entering the formula, I have to hit enter to convert it, which causes line breaks.

However, pressing the right(→) button only exits the editing box without rendering the formula.

Any shortcut?

Comment: How about space instead of enter?

Comment: @jonsson it simply insert a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following keyboard shortcut can prevent a newline from being created.

### On Windows:

- `alt + =`: Activate math mode to enter an equation
- `ctrl + =`: Convert the selected math mode from linear format to professional
- `ctrl + shift + =`: Convert the selected math mode from professional to linear format

### On Mac:

- `alt + =`: Activate math mode to enter an equation
- `command + =`: Convert the selected math mode from linear format to professional
- `command + shift + =`: Convert the selected math mode from professional to linear format

---

Reference: Tested on Microsoft Word for Mac v16.69